# how to get correct url in google search using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search, python-3.7

I am trying to get the first URL in the google search. Like I search "tcs" on google and it is giving http://www.tcs.com/. 
Mostly result is correct but sometimes I am not getting the correct URL. I want a solution for this.
try this on the google search:- "Euler Baubetr. u. Bauleitungsges. mbH"
and result is coming :-https://www.firmenwissen.com/.../EULER_BAUBETREUUNG_UND_ BAULEITUNGSGESELLSCHAFT_MBH.html

in output URL in middle ...... is coming

and the desired output is:- https://www.firmenwissen.com/en/az/firmeneintrag/63654/6110225969/EULER_BAUBETREUUNG_UND_BAULEITUNGSGESELLSCHAFT_MBH.html

### Code:-

```
   import requests

   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

   var="Euler Baubetr. u. Bauleitungsges. mbH"

   goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psyab&client=ubuntu&hs=k5b&channel=fs&biw=1366&bih=648&noj=1&q=" + var


   r = requests.get(goog_search)

   soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")

   url=soup.find('cite').text

   print(url)
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Please note that search engines are not deterministic - search rankings change over time.

Comment: current output:- ... is coming in middle
https://www.firmenwissen.com/.../EULER_BAUBETREUUNG_UND_ BAULEITUNGSGESELLSCHAFT_MBH.html

Comment: desired output:-
https://www.firmenwissen.com/en/az/firmeneintrag/63654/6110225969/EULER_BAUBETREUUNG_UND_BAULEITUNGSGESELLSCHAFT_MBH.html

Comment: I seem to getting the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate the correct href to get the url, see the code below...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

var="Euler Baubetr. u. Bauleitungsges. mbH"
goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psyab&client=ubuntu&hs=k5b&channel=fs&biw=1366&bih=648&noj=1&q=" + var

r = requests.get(goog_search)
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
url = soup.find('h3',attrs={'class':'r'}).a['href']
print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get more accurate results by passing [additional URL `parameters`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) such as country to search from, language, etc:

```py
params = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
response = requests.get('YOUR_URL', params=params)

# or in your case
params = {
  "q": "samurai cop, what does katana mean", # query
  "gl": "us",                                # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                                 # language 
  # additional parameters
}
```

To grab the first link, you're looking for this (`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)):

```py
first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

The next problem that will appear at some point is that there's was no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified. The default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit. User-agent fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
response = requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "Euler Baubetr. u. Bauleitungsges. mbH",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(first_link)

# https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/45d43c9f-f7d8-4f78-acde-14112341d038/y
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using the [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with such problems or maintain the parser over time since it's already done for the end-user, and the only thing that only needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want fast.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",                              # search engine to search from
    "q": "Euler Baubetr. u. Bauleitungsges. mbH",    # query
    "hl": "en",                                      # language
    "gl": "us",                                      # country to search from
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),                 # API key environment
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] first index result from organic results
first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/45d43c9f-f7d8-4f78-acde-14112341d038/y
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.